# How to send vibration to devices

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, vibration, airconsole

At some moments I need to send vibration to the devices because the players need to make selections through the device. How do I do this?
If there is a way to send vibration to all devices can anyone tell me how?
I tried this but it didn't work on some devices

Comment: did you try [`Handheld.Vibrate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handheld.Vibrate.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

The airconsole-api that you use in your controllers javascript offers an [airconsole.vibrate()](https://developers.airconsole.com/api/api-1-8-0/AirConsole-Controller_Inputs.html#vibrate) function. Using a message from your screen you can trigger it.

- The [pong example game](https://developers.airconsole.com/#!/guides/pong) shows how this messaging could be done with the guide explaining it in more detail. For unity it would be the same.
- The [Controller Test in airconsole-api](https://github.com/AirConsole/airconsole-api/blob/master/tests/spec/methods/spec-ctrl-inputs.js) shows the usage of airconsole.vibrate.

You would want to use airconsole.vibrate to avoid the browser specific navigator.vibrate resolution in the Pong Example. I will take note to update this and integrate it in the Unity example too.